# count occurrences among a set of words in r

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have a dataset like:

```
Col1
Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri
Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs
Mon,Tues,Wed
Mon,Tues
Thurs
```

And I want to give a score to each row, by counting a set of words.
Say I have this set of words: Mon, Tues, Wed

How do I make a column with corresponding scores? It will result in:

```
Scores
3
3
3
2
0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_count` after `paste`ing the `vector` of 'words'

```
library(stringr)
df1$Scores <- str_count(df1$Col1, paste(words, collapse="|"))
df1$Scores
#[1] 3 3 3 2 0
```

---

Or another option is `gregexpr` from `base R`

```
res <- gregexpr(paste0(words, collapse="|"), df1$Col1)
df1$Scores <-  lengths(res) * !sapply(res, function(x) -1 %in% x)
```

#### data

```
words <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed")
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri", "Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs", 
"Mon,Tues,Wed", "Mon,Tues", "Thurs")), .Names = "Col1",
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution:

```
words <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed");
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Col), ","), function(x) sum(x %in% words))
#[1] 3 3 3 2 0
```

Or to store in column `Scores`:

```
df$Scores <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Col), ","), function(x) sum(x %in% words));
df;
#                    Col1 Scores
#1 Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri      3
#2     Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs      3
#3           Mon,Tues,Wed      3
#4               Mon,Tues      2
#5                  Thurs      0
```

---

Or using `transform` and `purrr::map_int`

```
library(purrr);
transform(df, Scores = map_int(Col1, function(x) 
    sum(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ",")) %in% words)))
#                    Col1 Scores
#1 Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri      3
#2     Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs      3
#3           Mon,Tues,Wed      3
#4               Mon,Tues      2
#5                  Thurs      0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Col1
Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri
Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs
Mon,Tues,Wed
Mon,Tues
Thurs", header = T)
```